Iron-Session in Next.js 14: Session Not Updating After Refresh Token Flow
I'm using Iron-Session in a Next.js application to manage user sessions. The problem arises when I attempt to refresh the access token after it expires (HTTP 401 Unauthorized error).
Here’s the scenario:

When an API request fails with 401 Unauthorized, I send a request to the /api/refreshtoken endpoint to get a new access token using the refresh token (backend call) stored in the session.
After successfully fetching the new access token from backend, I attempt to update the session with the new token using session.save().

Observed Issue:

The session doesn’t update access token on the server side.
On retrying the original API request, the old (expired/first time login) access token is still being used.


actions/serverApi.js

export async function serverApi(url, method = "POST", data = {}, config = {}) {

  const session = await getIronSession(cookies(), ironOptions);
    const accessToken = session?.user?.access_token;
  
    if (!accessToken) {
      throw new Error("No access token found. Please log in.");
    }
  
    const headers = {
      ...config.headers,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };
  
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method,
        url: `${BASE_URL}${API_PREFIX}${url}`,
        data,
        headers,
      });
  
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {

      
      if (error.response?.status === 401) {
       
          // Next route handler called
          const refreshResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/refreshtoken", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Cookie": `gocustomai=${cookies().get("gocustomai").value}` },
            body: JSON.stringify(session),
            credentials: "include",
          });
          
          console.warn("401 Unauthorized - Refreshing token",error.response?.status);
  
        try {
  
          if (!refreshResponse.ok) {
            throw new Error("Token refresh failed. Please log in.");
          }
  
          const { authToken } = await refreshResponse.json();
  
          // Retry the original API request with the new token
          const retryHeaders = {
            ...headers,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
          };
  
          const retryResponse = await axios({
            method,
            url: `${BASE_URL}${API_PREFIX}${url}`,
            data,
            headers: retryHeaders,
          });
  
          return retryResponse.data;
        } catch (refreshError) {
          console.log("Authentication failed. Please log in again.");
        }
      }
  
      throw error;
    }
  }



api/refreshtoken/route.js

'use server';
import ironOptions from '@/config/ironOption';
import { getIronSession } from 'iron-session';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { LINK } from '@/config/config';

// Helper to adapt `NextRequest` to a Node-compatible `req` format
function adaptNextRequest(req) {
  return {
    headers: Object.fromEntries(req.headers.entries()),
    Cookie: req.Cookie,
  };
}

export async function POST(req) {
  const adaptedReq = adaptNextRequest(req);
  const res = NextResponse.next();

  try {
    // Get the current session
    const session = await getIronSession(adaptedReq, res, ironOptions);

    // Validate refresh token from body
    const currentRefreshToken = session?.user?.refresh_token;
    if (!currentRefreshToken) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "No refresh token provided. Please log in again." },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

    // Call backend to refresh the token
    const refreshResponse = await fetch(
      `${LINK.NODE_API_URL}/api/web/auth/refresh-token`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `jwt ${currentRefreshToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    if (!refreshResponse.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to refresh token from backend.");
    }

    const refreshData = await refreshResponse.json();
    const newAccessToken = refreshData?.data;

    if (!newAccessToken) {
      throw new Error("Invalid token data received.");
    }

    // Update session with new tokens
    session.user = {
      ...session.user,
      access_token: newAccessToken,
      refresh_token: currentRefreshToken, // Keep the same refresh token
    };

    await session.save();

    console.log("✅ Session updated successfully:", session.user);
    return NextResponse.json({ authToken: session.user }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("❌ Error refreshing token:", error.message);

    // Destroy session on failure
    const session = await getIronSession(adaptedReq, res, ironOptions);
    await session.destroy();

    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Token refresh failed. Please log in again." },
      { status: 401 }
    );
  }
}



What I’ve Tried:

Ensured session.save() is called: After updating the session with the new access token, I called session.save() to persist the changes.
Used correct cookie options: Double-checked the ironOptions configuration to ensure the session cookies are set properly (e.g., secure flags, cookie names).

What I Expected:

After receiving the new access token from the backend endpoint, I expected the session on the server to be updated with the new access token.
Upon retrying the original API request, after session.save() don't get 401 error again because new acess_token is updated.
The session data should be persisted and accessible in subsequent requests.

